Entity Framework query throws System.NullReferenceException when executing
I'm trying to execute this method:
public async Task<List<JobDetail>?> GetJobDetailsByJobIdAsync(int JobId)
{
    using ApplicationDbContext context = await _factory.CreateDbContextAsync();
    var jobDetails = await context.JobDetails
            .Where(q => q.JobId == JobId)
            .ToListAsync();
    return jobDetails;
}

Every time that var jobDetails line is executed, I get this error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

JobId always has a valid value.
This is the JobDetail model class:
public partial class JobDetail : IAuditable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; } = null!;
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Standard { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; } = 1;
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string? DrawingNumber { get; set; }
    public string? Size { get; set;}
    public string? BatchReference { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Certificate { get; set; }
    public string? Notes { get; set; }
    public int Released { get; set; }
    public int Balance { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int? MaterialId { get; set; }
    public int? ProcessId { get; set; }
    public decimal LineTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal LineTotalRemaining { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Created { get; set; }
    public string? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Modified { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DespatchDetail> DespatchDetails { get; set; } = new List<DespatchDetail>();

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Material? Material { get; set; }
    public virtual Process? Process { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SalesDetail> SalesDetails { get; set; } = new List<SalesDetail>();
}

And this is the table definition in the DbContext:
public virtual DbSet<JobDetail> JobDetails { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<JobDetail>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.BatchReference).HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.Description)
        .HasMaxLength(255)
        .HasDefaultValue("");
    entity.Property(e => e.Size)
        .HasMaxLength(255)
        .HasDefaultValue("");
    entity.Property(e => e.DrawingNumber).HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.JobId).HasColumnName("JobDetail_Job");
    entity.Property(e => e.MaterialId).HasColumnName("JobDetail_Material");
    entity.Property(e => e.ProcessId).HasColumnName("JobDetail_Process");
    entity.Property(e => e.LineTotal).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");
    entity.Property(e => e.LineTotalRemaining).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");
    entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedBy).HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.RowVersion)
        .IsRowVersion()
        .IsConcurrencyToken();
    entity.Property(e => e.Standard).HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.UnitPrice).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 2)");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Job).WithMany(p => p.JobDetails)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.JobId)
        .HasConstraintName("JobDetail_Job");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Material).WithMany(p => p.JobDetails)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.MaterialId)
        .HasConstraintName("JobDetail_Material");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Process).WithMany(p => p.JobDetails)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProcessId)
        .HasConstraintName("JobDetail_Process");
});

Everything seems to look fine to me. It should just return the collection of JobDetail for a Job where q.JobId == JobId.
However, as mentioned above every time that line is hit, it throws the exception.
A little context however, this is an old Lightswitch app that is being rewritten in Blazor. I took the models and DbContext configuration from Lightswitch. This has worked perfectly for the other 25+ tables so don't see any real reason why that should cause an issue but I just wanted to point that out.
There are 10,000s records in that table. Please tell me I'm missing something glaringly obvious because it's driving me insane.
Stack trace before the line executes:

And after:


The exception should tell you what was null too. Is it context.JobDetails?

@GSerg, I get a new tab in VS titled Break Mode with the text "The application is in break mode" - "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)." context is never null. At the break point I can see it initialised.

Does the query hit your server?

Job and JobId are not nullable. Check in your data that there always is a related Job.

Also, make sure there isn't an async void in the call chain.

@HenkHolterman There is. The code is executed from protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() from a Dialog. The Dialog is opened from the actual page in an async void method. Would that cause an issue?

It is possible, you should at least test this method from a 'normal' (async Task) code path.

@HenkHolterman I changed the void to a Task that the dialog opens opens from to no avail.

Have you checked the integrity of the data in the database and ensured it conforms to your model?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I have done this morning and it looks fine to me. In fact, on a more basic implementation on the home page, the service works. I'm leaning to it being something to do with opening in the Radzen Dialog.

So I have a fix, and I don't quite understand why this has worked, but it worked.

Copied and pasted the code I'd created in the Dialog component.
Deleted the component.
Recreated the component.
Copy and pasted the code back in.

Worked first time!
I came to this procedure after I tried the code on the home page to see if it was something to do with the dialog and it worked first time. I read the Radzen docs/help and couldn't see anything that would suggest what I was doing would be an issue.
That lead me to punt at recreating the component. And what would you know, it worked. A whole day wasted but hopefully this helps someone in the future.
Just for curiosity, I'll investigate it further and if I can come up with something substantive that makes sense as to what could cause the issue, I'll post it here.

Putting your code in (local) Git gives you a backup but can also help to pinpoint this kind of issues.

@HenkHolterman I use github and push regularly. There is no difference between the version of the component that didn't work vs the one that does. I can't even explain it.
